# Prevent draggable circle using Leaflet circle and leaflet-draw library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have a circle that I add to the map when you click on a specific point (centroid of that circle will be where the point is) and you can edit the circle, meaning you can resize it using the gripper on the end of the circle:

[image]

The resizing is working fine but what I want to do is prevent the circle from being draggable:

[image]

How do I disable dragging the circle but still keep the resizing? I am using the [leaflet-draw library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-draw) and as well as [@types/leaflet-draw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet-draw) packages. And here is how I am adding the circle to the map:

```
  onMapClick(leafletMouseEvent: LeafletMouseEvent) {
    const drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
      draw: {
        circle: true, // Enable circle drawing
      },
      edit: {
        featureGroup: new L.FeatureGroup()
      }
    });
    
    map.addControl(drawControl);
    
    // Initialize the feature group for drawn items
    drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);
    
    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, (e: any) => {
      let layer = e.layer;
      drawnItems.addLayer(layer); // Add shape to current drawing
    });
    
    map.on(L.Draw.Event.EDITED, (e: any) => {
      let layers = e.layers;
      layers.eachLayer((layer: any) => {
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
      });
    });
    
    const circle: any = new L.Circle(latLng, {
      radius: 1609.34, // 1 mile in meters
    });
    
    drawnItems.addLayer(circle);
    
    circle.editing.enable()
 }
```

Comment: leaflet-draw is not maintained anymore. I'd suggest to use Leaflet-Geoman instead where this is easily possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have only found [a hack](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/Lpyqzax1/) to prevent the circle from moving, maybe you can extend on it:

[image: animated map]

```js
'use strict';

var startPosition = [33.812511, -117.918976];
var map = L.map('mapId').setView(startPosition, 12);
var drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems,
    circle: {
      allowIntersection: false
    }
  }
}));

var circle = L.circle(startPosition, 1609.34).addTo(drawnItems);
circle.editing.enable();

map.on(L.Draw.Event.EDITMOVE, function(ev) {
  circle.setLatLng(ev.target._lastCenter);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mapId {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-draw@1/dist/leaflet.draw.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-draw@1/dist/leaflet.draw.min.css">

<div id="mapId"></div>
```